# Change attributes for a TextView from an inflated layout

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I have a list view whose margins and paddings I want to change dinamically, according with the screen density, so I need to set those attributes in java rather than xml, I was trying to inflate the item layout view and get its inner TextView, but the attributes don't change, here is my code:

this is the activity xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.onward.hemoapp.SearchDevicesActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="We've found the following devices:"
        android:id="@+id/devicesLabel"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@layout/device_list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="20.0sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/devicesLabel">

    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

this is the item layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/list_selector">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/deviceId"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@drawable/list_selector">
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

this is the piece of java code that I'm trying

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_devices);
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
float scale=metrics.density;
devicesLabel=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.devicesLabel);
devicesLabel.setPadding((int) (20 * scale), (int) (15 * scale), 0, (int) (15 * scale));
devicesLabel.setTextSize(10 * scale);
LinearLayout deviceList=(LinearLayout)LayoutInflater.from(SearchDevicesActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.device_list, null);
TextView deviceId=(TextView) deviceList.findViewById(R.id.deviceId);
deviceId.setPadding((int) (20 * scale), (int)(15 * scale), 0, (int) (15 * scale));
```

The TextView doesn't change its attributes, I tested many others and it remains the same

Comment: there is plenty of support given by android to support multiple screen using xml,.........The whole purpose of xml is to separate UI from the code to make things easy, that is android for you

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
LinearLayout deviceList=(LinearLayout)LayoutInflater.from(SearchDevicesActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.device_list, null);
TextView deviceId=(TextView) deviceList.findViewById(R.id.deviceId);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) deviceId.getLayoutParams();
params.setPadding((int) (20 * scale), (int)(15 * scale), 0, (int) (15 * scale))
deviceId.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: That ain't even exists

Answer (score 0):

You should put them in density specific XML files, in folders like `res/values-hdpi`, etc. then referencing them in your layout XML.